# Azure Elastic Job step to a privatelink sqldatabase target fails with "target principal name is incorrect" (Trust Server Certificate works in SSMS)

Tags: azure-sql-database, certificate

My first Elastic Job Agent jobstep to a privatelink sqldatabase target fails with "target principal name is incorrect." I can connect to servername.privatelink.database.windows.net and the specific database in SSMS with the same SQL login if I check "Trust Server Certificate" on the connection options, so the elastic job login, credentials, user are set up correctly. I don't see a way to specify Trust Server Certificate when setting up the jobstep.  The Azure sql server has transparent data encryption enabled via a service managed certificate, as do all the databases on the sql server (via inheritance, i assume).  Is there any way to force the job step to trust server cert?  Thanks!

Comment: Most of the people don't know what an Elastic Job Agent is. Pasting some code might trill us and push us to find a solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There's not really any code for this other than the usual t-sql to create the job, step, target, target members, logins, credentials and users. I apologize if I'm misunderstanding this site, but if you don't know what an elastic job agent is, why would you try to answer a question about it? Aren't people posting questions and problems here looking for expertise or experiience in the subject matter and it's answers? Hopefully someone else has experienced this same specific issue and will share their solution. Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow and dba.stackexchange.com are very useful website. To give you an example I've subscribed with an RSS feed to all questions related tu `Azure` and believe me: I don't receive more than 1-2 questions per week. Azure has not been adopted from a wide audience. Most of the companies do "Lift & Shift" and they basically migrate their servers to Azure VMs. Finding experts in Azure SQL DB or Managed Instance is not easy, that's why no one replied to your question. With SQL Server people copy/paste the code on their machine and they give you a reply but...

Comment: ...with Azure is different: If I want to help you I have to create an Azure SQL DB, and spend money in order to help you. And that's why no one replied to your question. But from my experience, if you post at least some code, there is the chance that people gets trilled. For example people like me that need to migrate DB to Azure and need to study Elastc Agent Job and Azure Data Factory. I will try to help you if I have time but please, help me help you